# RHEL5 Xen dom0 max memory?

Tags: linux, virtualization, memory, xen

I have a server with 48GB or RAM on which I have installed RHEL5 with the xen kernel.  I think maybe this is normal behavior, but the kernel only seems to be able to see 32GB.  I looked around online, and I found very little.  I think a significant data point is that `xm info` reports `total_memory` as 49142 (MB, I assume), which I suppose means that I can utilize the 48GB for my VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `xm info` reports all of the RAM then you should be able to assign it out to your domU's without a problem. I typically set the `dom0_mem` setting on the grub.conf boot line to limit the RAM the dom0 can utilize and save the rest for the domU's. I couple this with setting `dom0-min-mem` to 0 in `xend-config.sxp` to keep it from ballooning larger.

I'm not aware if there is a 32GB limit to the dom0, but I've not had a system with that much RAM to be able to test it either. Xen requires a PAE-based kernel build so it should be able to address the RAM.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy.  I often forget that the dom0 is just another domain, although it has some extra privileges.  I'll feel a little better if I could find a reference to a 32GB limit on memory in Xen domains, but that does seem to be the case.

Comment: Correct... The Xen hypervisor is actually loaded by GRUB and then it starts dom0 as the privileged domain. The domU is really no different from the dom0 except it's unprivileged. I use the dom0 only for a management backplane so usually limit it to 1 vCPU and 256M RAM.